# Uniformly converge

Tags: calculus

fn(x) is a sequence of continuous function at [a,b] that uniformly convergent to f(x) at [a,b].
Prove that for all p>0:

Lim(integral |fn(x)-f(x)|^p from a to b)dx when n to infinity =0

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$,

As $f_n \to f$ uniformly, there exist $N$ such that for $n \geq N, \forall x\in [a,b]$, you have $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \left( \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

this imply that for $n \geq N$

$$ 0 \leq \int_a^b |f_n(x)-f(x)|^p dx \leq \int_a^b \left| \left( \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \right|^p dx = \epsilon$$